# Problems with standard function <stdarg.h>

Tags: c

I'm trying to do something like a dictionary for c. I want that different types of data to be stored in a dictionary. In order to get an unlimited number of values, I used *stdarg.h* but got a problem with determining the data type. I have a few questions:

**How can I determine the data type of each element?**

**How can I create a loop that will work until the elements are over?**

For example this code from K&R

```
include <stdarg.h>
/* minprintf: минимальный printf с переменным числом аргумент */
void minprintf(char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list ар; /* указывает на очередной безымянный аргумент */
    char *p, *sval;
    int ival;
    double dval;
    va_start(ap, fmt); /* устанавливает ар на 1-й безымянный аргумент */
    for (p = fmt; *р; р++) {
        if (*p != '%') {
            putchar(*p);
            continue;
        }
        switch (*++р) {
        case 'd':
            ival = va_arg(ap, int);
            printf ("%d", ival);
            break;
        case 'f':
            dval = va_arg(ap, double);
            printf("%f", dval);
            break;
        case 's':
            for (sval = va_arg(ap, char *); *sval; sval++)
            putchar(*sval);
            break;
        default:
            putchar(*p);
            break;
        }
    }
    va_end(ap); /* очистка, когда все сделано */
}
```

And here *fmt* is string that contains quantity elements.

**But how can I write a function that doesn't contains this string?**

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void test (const char *, ...);

int main ()
{
    test("Hello", "world", 15, 16.000);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot for taking your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot.

C simply doesn't provide any way for a variadic function to independently detect the types of arguments that were passed, nor the number of them.  So you have to design your function such that it can work this out from other information provided by the caller.

Answer (score 1):

You can.

Since C99,

> How can I determine the data type of each element?

Use `_Generic`

> How can I create a loop that will work until the elements are over?

See below

---

Change the call to use a macro `GARI(obj)`

```
// test("Hello", "world", 15, 16.000);
test(GARI("Hello"), GARI("world"), GARI(15), GARI(16.000), 0);
```

`GARI` is a macro the uses `_Generic` to distinguish types and provide an enumerator. Then 2 arguments to `test` are passed: an enumerator to ID the type and then the object itself.

This obliges `_Generic` to enumerate many types.  There are infinite numbers of possible types, but a basic list `_Bool, char, long long, double, char *`, etc. is reasonable.

Then `test()` uses the enumeration to steer selection of the next argument.  Recommend a `0` to end the list.

---

This is all not a simple coding nor something for a learner.

"example this code from K&R" --> C have evolved in 40+ years. Consider newer references.

Comment: well I closed this q/a as a duplicate of the other just as you posted this, maybe you could move the to the target

Comment: @AnttiHaapala OK - Added answer there.